# How to start with page number in php pagination?

Tags: php

I have PHP pagination which is showing previous and first page number active but it should not show active class. I have tried with the below code and for the search results I don't have page number in the URL. How to show the pagination with current page?

```
$limit = 20;                    
$total = count($_productCollection); //150
$total_pages = ceil($total / $limit);  
$page=1; 


    echo "<ul class='pagination'>";
echo "<li><a href='index.php?page=".($page-1)."' class='button'>Previous</a></li>"; 

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {  
    echo "<li><a href='index.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>";
};  

echo "<li><a href='index.php?page=".($page+1)."' class='button'>NEXT</a></li>";
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: What do you mean by `active class` ? You can get the current page by doing a `$_GET['page'];`

Comment: if there are no page in query string how to do it

Comment: How to show prev 1 2 3 4 ....  150 next

Answer (score 1):

You should add active class to `<li>` element when the actual page is equal with `$i` variable.

The problem you have is that you use `$page` variable static (it's always = 1). You should get the value of page from `$_GET['page']` variable.

Also I have added a condition to check if it's first page to not show the previous.

```
<?php

$limit = 20;                    
$total = count($_productCollection); //150
$total_pages = ceil($total / $limit);  
$page= isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1; ; 

?>
```

First way to add html with PHP:

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <?php 
        //if its first page don't show previous ( Also you need to do the same thing for last page)
        if ($page > 1) { ?>
            <li><a href="index.php?page=<?php echo $page-1 ?>"> Previous </a></li>

    <?php } ?>


        <?php for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {  
            //if its active page add active variable
            if($page == $i){
                $class = 'active';
            }else{
                $class = '';
            }

            ?>
            <li class="<?php echo $class; ?>"><a href='index.php?page=<?php echo $i ?>'><?php echo $i ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
    <li><a href="index.php?page=<?php echo $page + 1 ?>"> NEXT </a></li>

</ul>
```

Second way to add html using `echo` to print `html` elements:

```
echo '<ul class="pagination">';

    //if its first page don't show previous ( Also you need to do the same thing for last page)
    if ($page > 1) { 
        echo '<li><a href="index.php?page='.($page-1).'"> Previous </a></li>';
    } 


     for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {  
        if($page == $i){
            $class = 'active';
        }else{
            $class = '';
        }


        echo '<li class="'.$class.'"><a href="index.php?page='.$i.' ">$i</a></li>';
  } 
  echo '<li><a href="index.php?page='.($page + 1).'"> NEXT </a></li>';

  echo '</ul>'
```

**EDIT**

This code can do what you want but it's not the way you should do it. Let's say you have more than 100 pages. What will happen? You show all pages so all your numbers are in screen. I would suggest to use some `jQuery` libraries. Check out this one [simplePagination](http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/). It will help you achieve `prev 1 2 3 ... 150 next` in a very simple way.

Comment: @mike did you fixed it or you need more help?

Answer (score 0):

**I made some minor changes in your code. It should work perfectly.**

> Copy and paste the below code

```
$limit = 20;                    
$total = count($_productCollection); //150
$total_pages = ceil($total / $limit);  
$page= isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1; //get page from request or default 1


echo "<ul class='pagination'>";

if($page > 1) //only show prev if current page is greater than 1
   echo "<li><a href='index.php?page=".($page-1)."' class='button'>Previous</a></li>"; 

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {  
    if($i == $page){
       echo "<li class='active'> <span>".$page."</span></li>";
    }else{
       echo "<li><a href='index.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>";
    }

};  

if($page < $total_pages) //only show next if current page is less than total page
  echo "<li><a href='index.php?page=".($page+1)."' class='button'>NEXT</a></li>";

echo "</ul>";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {  
        echo "<li class='" . ( $i == $page?'active':'' ) . "'>
<a href='index.php?page=".$i."'> ".$i."</a></li>";
    };
```

Comment: $page = 1. assuming he said that he dont know (i dont have page number in the url). then he ask (how to show the pagination with current page.) 

I am not sure why it is not an appropriate answer.

I am sure it would hightlight the number 1 in the pagination.